# Starting Google Maps as default activity

Tags: android, android-intent, maps

I want to start a Google Maps activity from a button click.

It works great:

```
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, url);
          mapIntent.setData(url);
          startActivity(mapIntent);
```

... but I really want to hide the intent chooser between **Browser** and **Maps**. I want to make the button open directly Google Maps.

I tried adding **geo:0,0?q=** as a prefix to the URL, and this works. But, for reasons I am not able to explain, I can't use this notation or my app would not work.

In other words: Can I invoke directly the Google Maps class from its package to start it as an Intent?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you would get "the intent chooser between Browser and Maps" is if your URL is an `http://` URL. The proper way to open the Google Maps Android app is to [use a `geo:` URL](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html), not an `http://` URL.

> I tried adding geo:0,0?q= as a prefix to the URL, and this works. But, for reasons I am not able to explain, I can't use this notation or my app would not work.

Then write a different app. Or, open the Google Maps Web site rather than the Google Maps Android app.